# jQuery UI autocomplete works in development perfectly, almost works in production

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I have a rails app that has an jquery ui autocomplete search input. It works perfectly in development and even sends the request to the server in production mode, so everything until the dropdown is working perfectly. The problem is that the autocomplete dropdown is not showing, not even an empty dropdown.

I don't know why this is happening because it works perfectly in development. It didn't work on Heroku, and now I've switched to EC2 it doesn't work either. Same outcome.

I know its normal to show some code, but I don't know what to show if the associated code is working fine.

Has anyone else had this problem? If you request code I'll post it.

application.css.sass

```
@import jquery.ui.all
@import variables.css.scss
@import bootstrap
@import sass-rules.css.scss
@import fonts.css.scss
@import general.css.scss
@import containers.css.scss
@import jquery.Jcrop.min
@import header.css.scss
@import side_bar.css.scss
@import modal.css.scss
@import home.css.scss
@import users.css.scss
@import items.css.scss
@import messages.css.scss
@import notifications.css.scss
@import me.css.scss
@import friends.css.scss
@import discover.css.scss
```

Comment: Have you checked the dev console to see if any of the jquery files is failing to load?

Comment: In addition to what @hsalama mentioned, are you also including the accompanying css in your production environment?

Comment: @hsalama - Everything is served perfectly in the dev console.

Comment: @Mark - do you mean precompiling?

Comment: @Dol Are you including jqueryui js and css files through the assets pipeline or serving them through a CDN?

Comment: @Mark - assets pipeline. I've converted the application.css to .css.sass and am importing all the files, I've put Jquery.ui first.

Comment: If you're not seeing any javascript errors in the console, it would seem that you've at least got all your assets setup correctly.

Comment: @Mark - Yeah its all working nicely. In development it works like a charm. In production works perfectly until it has to display the results - I can even see the successful search on the production logs. Same thing has happened on Heroku and EC2. And strangely enough, with and without the jquery ui gem (I was loading it as a script before).

Comment: This may be a peanut gallery comment, but the technical syntax for @import is "quoted" text. Maybe there's an error between your local dev maching parsing the file vs server side? Feel free to disregard... :)

Comment: hmmm. I think because its written in sass its not quoted. but I could be wrong, I'm quite new to using sass. There is definitely something wrong on the production server, but everything else is working fine... Its really a bizarre error. Thanks for your input! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Here's what happened...

I was using SQLite3 in development mode and PostgreSQL in production. SQLite was searching the database and returning case insensitive results, while PostgreSQL was returning case sensitive results, therefore while testing in production, it returned no results, an empty hash. And being the only jQuery UI component I'm using, I thought that the css was broken.